# Recommend troubleshooting steps for a Dell Sonicwall Netextender VPN that is intermitently extremely slow?

Tags: vpn, windows-7

So I'm a developer and need to work from home on occasion and my company's VPN is slow as dirt, only for me apparently.  Once i connect to VPN it doesnt really matter what im accessing (ie website, database, network share, etc.), sometimes it is slightly slower than in the office and then a minute later it's almost not responsive or like dial-up speed.  Ping is all over the place from 50ms to 1200ms.  Speedtest vary too depending on it's mood.

My home internet is high-speed cable and is not the problem.  I've installed the vpn client on a home computer and it works fine without any slowness. So that leads me to believe the issue is with my work computer.

So far I've tried reinstalling the client, and turning off any unnecessary programs and services but with no luck.  My company's IT support is baffled, they had me try a different client connecting to a different server in my local office, but that didnt help either.

Any suggestions that i can try or relay to support?

Comment: Are you using wifi? What are the environmental differences between the home pc, and the work pc?

Comment: Both computers are on wifi and both are running windows 7 that was installed within the past 6 months.  The work PC has a lot more applications installed and is obviously part of the company domain.

Comment: You need to figure out what bandwidth your company is using for the VPN service.  Once you know that, you'll have a baseline for ideal performance.  Then, you need to gather data from others who are working remotely as well, to compare your experience to theres.  After you have all that, you need to determine if your ISP is purposely degrading your performance over port 1723; lots of broadband vendors do this as standard without telling their customers, to "save" on bandwidth.  Lastly, your company's IT people are pretty useless if they're baffled by this, since they have access to the logs.

Comment: Since your home pc works, I would imagine there is an issue between your work laptop, and your router. Try a wired connection, try someone else's Internet (wifi hotspot, etc.). If your companies IT isn't looking more into the issue, more than likely everyone else is working fine and you are an isolated issue. Eliminate the wireless, I've seen issues with old encryption implementations that caused issues, just switching from TKIP, to AES solved my problem. Once you eliminate your personal wireless connection as the issue, send your IT a list of things you tried including eliminating the wireles

Comment: I was told by product support that NetExtender only makes use of 12% of the remote connections download speed. I don't understand why but, it seems true.